# select MySQL value where value is equal to a value but not equal to other value

Tags: mysql

I have to select all value where some column are equal to a values but exclude other values

```
|   ID   |   Name  |   V1   |   V2   |   V3   | index |
|   1    |    A    |   1    |   NULL |   5    |   1   |
|   2    |    B    |   15   |   NULL |   1    |   3   |
|   3    |    C    |   8    |   15   |   5    |   2   |
|   4    |    D    |   8    |   1    |   5    |   1   |
```

So I have

```
SELECT * from table where (V1 IN (1,15) or V2 IN (1,15) or V3 IN (1,15))
```

If I do this the query select also ID 1 and 3... So I want to exclude before V1,V2,V3 NOT IN (5,8)

I want display all rows contain 1 or 15 but if there is an other value as 8 or 5 not display the row.

---

I'm sorry, the best thing it would be:
- index is the column name V with index so V1

so the best way is select all rows in table where the columnINDEX is IN (1,15)

I want display row ID 1 because the index column tell in column V1 there is the value 1
I want display row ID 2 because the index column tell in column V3 there is the value 1
I want display row ID 3 because the index column tell in column V2 there is the value 1
row ID 4 not display because the index column tell in column V1 there is the value 8

---

**V1,V2,V3 are int type**

Comment: I assume that second `V2` should be a `V3`

Comment: yes sorry, I correct the post

Comment: *I want display row ID 3 because the index column tell in column V2 there is the value 1* the value is 15 and also there is 8 in v1 and 5 in v3. Why do you want this row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE (   FIND_IN_SET(1, CONCAT_WS(',',V1,V2,V3)) 
        + FIND_IN_SET(15, CONCAT_WS(',',V1,V2,V3))
      )
  AND NOT (   FIND_IN_SET(5, CONCAT_WS(',',V1,V2,V3)) 
            + FIND_IN_SET(8, CONCAT_WS(',',V1,V2,V3))
          );
```

Comment: Hi, this not work, I haven't any result with 15 value

Comment: it works in example table but not in my true table, in my table I see only rows with value 1

Comment: @pette Edited, test.

Answer (score 0):

So your result should be row ID `2` by itself, correct?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (
    5 NOT IN (V1,V2,V3)
    AND
    8 NOT IN (V1,V2,V3)
    AND 
    (
        1 IN (V1,V2,V3)
        OR
        15 IN (V1,V2,V3)
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi, I haven't any result with '15' value, so it doesn't work

Comment: it works in example table but not in my true table, in my table I see only rows with value 1

Comment: My V1, V2, V3 are int type. If I have varchar works, but with int type no

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to have all V1 = 1 or 15 and then exclude all V2 or V3 that != 5 or 8

SELECT * FROM table WHERE V1 IN (1, 15) and (V1 NOT IN (5, 8) or V2 NOT IN (5, 8) or V3 NOT IN (5,8)) AND V2 IN (1, 15) and (V1 NOT IN (5, 8)...

Comment: No, I want all V1,V2,V3 contain 1 or 15 but exclude all V1,V2,V3 contain 5 or 8